# AutoCAD: make a solid out of a set of cross sections of an object

Tags: graphics, 3d, modeling, autocad, cad

I have an object that looks like this (the canopy of a paraglider):

[image]

I want to convert it to a solid object (to add the textile cloth that's missing). In other words, to connect each cross section to the next using roughly longitudinal lines.

Is there a way to do this in AutoCAD ? For example, viewing each pair of consecutive cross sections as a polyline, the result would be a wall from one cross section to the next.

Would reading the DXF using an independent (python for example) script and adding the polygons programatically be an option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a command called `Loft`, I'm not sure it's available in AutoCAD. For sure you can find it inside Autodesk Inventor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NosVftq7zHM

Comment: Alberto is right! It is available in AutoCAD ("_LOFT" command).

Comment: Definitely the way to go. Off topic, but is there a way to convert my cross sections which are all separate lines into polylines ? PEDIT seems to require all lines to be in the XY plane.